# Get data from text input without using two-way data binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

Long story short, it works if I change `<` to `=` here:

```
const rtmNav = {
    bindings: {
        from:'<',
        to:'<',
        submit: '&'
    },
    controller: angular.noop,
    templateUrl: require('./rtmNav.html')
}

export default rtmNav;
```

This is the controller where `dataa` object is defined:

```
class DemandCtrl {
    constructor(ChartDataService) {
        this.ChartDataService = ChartDataService;
        debugger;
        this.dataa = {
            from: '10/01/2017',
            to:  '10/03/2017'
        };
    }

    $onInit() {
        getData.call(null, this);       
    }

    update() {

        getData.call(null, this);       
    }
}
```

The component looks like this:

```
<div class="rtm-nav">   
    <div ng-app>
    <form ng-submit="$ctrl.submit()">
        <label>From:
            <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="$ctrl.from">
        </label>
        <label>To:
            <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="$ctrl.to">
        </label>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Apply" />
    </form> 
    </div>
</div>
```

And the html page like this:

```
<div class="demand page">   
    <rtm-header title="Demand" icon="fa fa-line-chart" link=true></rtm-header> 
    <rtm-nav from="$ctrl.dataa.from", to="$ctrl.dataa.to", submit="$ctrl.update()">         
    </rtm-nav> 
    <div id="chart" class="demand-chart">
    </div>
</div>
```

When I first run the application, it shows the chart between the hardcoded values (`10/01/2017` and `10/03/2017`). If it is made as two-way data binding, if I change those values and click on `apply` it will re-render the chart with the new data.

My constraint is do to it one-way data binding.

I don't know how to do it, show I send the new parameters in `update()` or should I add them somehow in the component?

Comment: Two-way data binding: `ng-model="something"` or `{{something}}`. One-way data binding: `ng-bind="something"` or `{{::something}}`

Comment: tried this way but now when I run the app for the first time, the text inputs are empty (before they contained the hardcoded values). anyway, if I introduce other values, for each values I write the chart is for the hardcoded values I talk about  (`10/01/2017` and  `10/03/2017`). Yeah I know, it's strange

Comment: Can you use `$scope.one = angular.copy($scope.two);` in your example? So on apply / submit you would take a copy and not affect other scope variables

Comment: I don't understand it clear, sorry. Where should I put it? And why `one` and `two`?

Comment: That's what I meant: [https://plnkr.co/edit/rraQ3z4cFCEtVIYM4qD3?p=preview](https://plnkr.co/edit/rraQ3z4cFCEtVIYM4qD3?p=preview)

Comment: I appreciate your help but in your case they are on the same page. I need to send the data from html to the controller. Or the controller to be able to read what's in the text inputs